# Javascript conflict with jQuery plugin - working on test page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to use the smooth scroll by smoothdivscroll dot com/#quickdemo , but I am getting a js conflict.  I have it working on a test page, http://www.visfire.com/scroll.html, but it does not work on the live page viwfire dot com /Design/Logo-CorporateIdDesign.aspx . According to Firebug, "$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll is not a function."

Should I replace the "$" with something else?

Also the latest work module on the same page quit working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to replace that $ with jQuery if you have conflict javascript libraries, say, prototype in use on the same page.

[reference](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

I will say your issue seems more like a corrupted jQuery plugin, can you use Firebug to inspect your actual page and check if the smoothScroll plugin is fully loaded?

Comment: Firebug says there are no breakpoints on this page, but it does list one error "$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll is not a function
[Break on this error] $("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivS...tAtMe", visibleHotSpots: "always"}); "

Comment: @Cory1970: then try replacing it with jQuery and see how it goes.